# How to test if zeros have changed to ones (but not the other way around)

Tags: c, binary

I have a binary mask which at some point I'm updating. It's ok for 1s in my old mask to become 0s but the other way around is not allowed. How can I assert using some binary operations that none of the 0s in the mask have turned into 1s?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if (~old & new)
```

If you also want to know which bits changed from 0 to 1, just read each bit in `bits = ~old & new;`. If you just want to know if any 0s became 1s, that first line of code will do.

Comment: But they *don't* want to know (just) which bits have changed.  They want to know whether any bits that were 0 in `old` are flipped to 1 in `new`.

Comment: @JohnBollinger and for that it is sufficient to ignore the last sentence

Comment: @JohnBollinger  Now it's better phrased, I hope.

Answer (score 1):

So we have old mask and new mask, and none of the 0s of the old mask must have been set in the new mask.

Solution is simple: invert the old mask, turning all zeroes into ones and ones into zeroes. **And** the result with the new mask - if result is nonzero the undesired thing has happened.

Demonstrating this with a minimal example. We have

```
old = 0011
new = 1001
```

There are two bits that have changed, two bits are unchanged; one change is undesirable. We invert the `old`, with `~` and **and** it with `new`:

```
 ~old = 1100
  new = 1001
& ----------
        1000
```

the result is nonzero so we know that a zero was changed to one.

For code see [Cacahuete's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55926699/918959)